# How to force a variable to be local in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

Given the following code:

```
outer=1
f=->
  local=1
  outer=0
  local+outer
```

coffeescript creates a `var` for `local` but re-ueses `outer`:

```
var f, outer;

outer = 1;

f = function() {
  var local;
  local = 1;
  outer = 0;
  return local + outer;
};
```

Which is what your expect.

However, if you use a local variable in a function it depends on the outer scope if the variable is declared local or not. I know this is a feature, but it was causing some bugs, because I have to check all outer scopes for variables with the same name (which are declared before my function). I wonder if there is a way to prevent this type of bug by declaring variables local?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This kind of error usually comes up when you aren't using appropriately descriptive variable names.  That said, there is a way to shadow an outer variable, despite what the accepted answer says:

```
outer=1
f=->
  do (outer) ->
    local=1
    outer=0
    local+outer
```

This creates an IIFE, with `outer` as it's one argument.  Function arguments shadow outer variables just like the `var` keyword, so this will have the behavior you expect.  However, like I said, you should really just name your variables more descriptively.

Comment: `do` is very helpful to *freeze* the state of an outer variable. However, I think the problem of accidentally using an outer variable is inherent in the way the scoping of coffeescript is designed...

Comment: In the moment I would use the `do` as you describe it, I would know that `outer` is shadowing the outer variable. In that case I can avoid it by using another name. I was talking about accidentally naming a variable like an outer variable. This can be tricky if you move a function to another place and suddenly there is a variable inherited form the outer scope that otherwise be local.... I was looking for a pattern to make sure all I want to be local variables are local... One could use the `do` for all local variables, but that would be strange....

Comment: @Michael_Scharf I understand that this may not solve your problem (which is why I suggest more descriptive names - in practice, I've never actually had this problem, so I suspect that it is avoidable).  However, the accepted answer said "it's impossible to shadow an outer variable on purpose", which is clearly not true, so I felt the need to correct it.

Answer (score 6):

No, that feature is explicitly **not** available in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) (emphasis mine):

> This behavior is effectively identical to Ruby's scope for local variables. Because you don't have direct access to the `var` keyword, **it's impossible to shadow an outer variable on purpose, you may only refer to it**. So be careful that you're not reusing the name of an external variable accidentally, if you're writing a deeply nested function.

Comment: I see. In python, for example, you can access outer variables but not modify them (in python 3.x there is a keyword ```nonlocal``` to do that). I think, the implicit modification of outer variables may be error prone....

Answer (score 6):

You can inject plain JavaScript into your CoffeeScript using backticks:

```
outer=1
f=->
  local=1
  `var outer=0`
  local+outer
```

For most cases I try to avoid this and would rather rename the outer variables, indicating their scope/context within their name. However, sometimes this is helpful, e.g., when using the *debug* module, where I always want to have a `debug()` function available for logging, as in this example:

```
#logging fn for module setup and other global stuff
debug = require("debug")("foo")

class Bar
  #local logging fn to allow Bar instances to log stuff
  `var debug = require("debug")("foo:bar")`
```

If you want to keep plain JS at a minimum just declare the variable and then assign is using CoffeeScript:

```
  `var debug`; debug = require("debug") "foo:bar"
```

The example compiles to:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1 -- removed empty lines for SO answer
var Bar, debug;    
debug = require("debug")("foo");    
Bar = (function() {
  function Bar() {}    
  var debug;    
  debug = require("debug")("foo:bar");    
  return Bar;    
})();
```

I like this direct way of declaring variables better than the (IMHO) slower and less readable IIFE hack.

Answer (score 2):

As Aaron pointed out, shadowing is indeed possible:

```
outer=1
f=->
  do (outer) ->
    local=1
    outer=0
    local+outer
```

Since the outer value is not needed inside the local function, it can be initialized with `null` just in case that at some point the variable `outer` is removed from the outer scope (which would cause an error).

```
#outer=1
f=->
  do (outer=null) ->
    local=1
    outer=0
    local+outer
```

Comment: +1. But I would probably use `outer=undefined` unless the `null` value is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
important = 10 # global

main = ->
    agentId = '007'
    console.log 'global `important`', important # refers to the global variable

    ((important) -> # place the local variables as the arguments
        important = 20
        console.log 'local `important`', important # locally scoped
        console.log 'parent scope value', agentId # even access variables from the above scopes
    )() # not passing anything, so the local varibales would be left undefined at first

    console.log 'global `important`', important # the global variable remains untouched

main()
```

Comment: instead of `((important) -> ...)()` you could write `do (important) -> ...`. This saves you some '()'. Both versions compile to the same javascript.

Comment: @Michael_Scharf I guess that would be wrong because it translates to (function(important) { ... })(important) as I don't intend to pass any args

Comment: The way to get around would be do (important=undefined) ->.And yeah the do-syntax makes it much more condensed.

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to comment on the accepted answer (but SO rep says no), saying that the `do` paradigm should be fundamental lore when using coffeescript, just as the OP suggested in comments.

This feature of coffeescript is the proverbial "footgun", and could be addressed better in the language than suggesting that the "right way" is

```
outer = 1
f = -> do (outer=0) ->
  local=1
  local+outer
```

No doubt the "better" way is up for much debate, so I'm not proposing a particular solution here, see this discussion for more: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4985

Coffeescript is a lovely language to use, but IMO if it wants to continue with real purpose then an issue like this, which has existed for some time, should be addressed.